# Subset of table in R using row numbers?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several rows and I want to create a new data table with specific rows from the larger table. I want the new table to have only the rows where

```
(row number)%3 != 2
```

Basically, I want rows 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, etc. Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps using the *subset* operation?

Thanks!

Comment: square brackets or the `select` argument to the `subset` command.  I strongly recommend reading the `Introduction to R`! http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data frame is `df`:

```
df[1:NROW(df) %% 3 != 2, ]
```